# How to retrieve data from db and display it on input field dynamic using jquery #codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This code still not working, I had some kind of dynamic input field from this forum,like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var counter = 2;
   $("#addField").click(function () {
   if(counter>110){
           alert("Only 110 textboxes allow");
           return false;
   }

var newTextDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("id", 'TextDiv' + counter);
newTextDiv.after().html('<table class="table">'+
       '<tr>' +
       '<td width="400" style="padding: 10px;">' +
       '<p style="color: teal; font-size: 14px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Building '+ counter +'</p>' +
       '<label class="control-label">Building name :</label>' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="id_building_name' + counter +'" name="field[building_name][]'+ counter +'"/>' +
       '<label class="control-label">Year build :</label>' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="id_year_build'+ counter +'" name="field[year_build][]'+ counter +'"/>' +
       '</td>' +
       '</tr>' +
        '</table>'
    );
    
  newTextDiv.appendTo("#TextGroup");
   counter++;
    });

   $("#removeField").click(function () {
     if(counter==1){
           alert("No more textbox to remove");
           return false;
        }
    counter--;
    $("#TextDiv" + counter).remove();
   });
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id='TextGroup'>
  <div id="TextDiv">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <p style="margin-left: 25px; color: teal; font-size: 14px;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>     Building 1</p>
<td>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Building name :</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="id_building_name1" name="field[building_name][]"/>
    <label class="control-label">Year build :</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="id_year_build1" name="field[year_build][]"/>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td>
<div class="box-main" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
<label>Is there any other building ?</label><br/>
<input type='button' value='Add Field' id='addField' class="btn btn-info btn-sm">&nbsp; 
<input type='button' value='Remove Field' id='removeField' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">&nbsp;
<input type='button' value='Edit Value' id='editValue' class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
</div>
</td> 
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Using jquery and then success save to db..the problem is how to put data (Edit data transaction) into dynamic input field?
please help..thanks

Comment: hi got solutions for this post

Comment: hi bro `@Deep `..actually i use manual form for post value..that not effective..but if you or anyone can resolve this..i appreciate that for  my new experience .thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the exact code of your but it will give idea how to dump and populate dynamic fields in form. Go through comments in code snippet.

This is view file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>controller/desired_controller_dump_function">
    <div class="controls">
        <dynamic>
            <label for="other_charges">Add Tiered Discount & Qty <small>(click the green button to add more)</small>
            </label>
            <br>

            <?php 
            //assuming $dynamic_fields_form_data is result of row_array() in codeigniter; 
            $discount_quantity_arr=json_decode($dynamic_fields_form_data[ 'discount_quantity'],true); //converting from json string to array 
            $discount_percentage_arr=json_decode($dynamic_fields_form_data[ 'discount_percentage'],true); 
     //$discount_quantity_arr=[]; //for testing code without data
     //$discount_percentage_arr=[]; //for testing code without data

            if(!empty($discount_percentage_arr)){ foreach($discount_percentage_arr as $k=> $v){ ?>
            <div class="entry input-group col-xs-12 form-group ">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input class="form-control" name="discount_quantity[]" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" value="<?php echo $discount_quantity_arr[$k]?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input class="form-control" name="discount_percentage[]" type="number" placeholder="percentage" value="<?php echo  $discount_percentage_arr[$k]?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <?php
                                if($k+1==count($discount_percentage_arr)){
                            ?>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button" style="font-size:2vh">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </button>

                        <?php } else{ ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-remove btn-danger" type="button" style="font-size:2vh">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                        </button>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <?php } }else{ ?>

            <div class="entry input-group col-xs-12 form-group ">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input class="form-control" name="discount_quantity[]" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input class="form-control" name="discount_percentage[]" type="number" placeholder="percentage" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button" style="font-size:2vh">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <?php } ?>

        </dynamic>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var controlForm = $('.controls dynamic:first');
            var currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first');
            var newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

            newEntry.find('input').val('');
            controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
                .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
        }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
            $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    })
</script>
```

This is controller function

```
public function desired_controller_dump_function(){
    extract($this->input->post());
    $discount_quantity=json_encode($discount_quantity); //change to json string and save in database as string
    $discount_percentage=json_encode($discount_percentage);
    //save this variable in database through model
    $this->model_function->dumpdata($discount_quantity,$discount_percentage);
   //remaining process

}

public function desired_controller_get_function(){
    $data['dynamic_fields_form_data']=$this->model_function->getdata();//function to get data from database through model
    $this->load->view('dynamic_field_file',$data);
}
```

Comment: great code..ill try..thanks for always help bro @Deep 3015